# How to enable the "idle" command from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-line, python-idle

I remember that at some point I used to be able open up the python IDLE from the command line by simply typing "idle" return, which would pop up the python idle editor. I recently got a new machine and installed python, but have to open idle from the windows start menu.

When trying to run "idle" or "idle3" from the command line I get

```
C:\Users\SSims>idle3
'idle3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the command line "idle" command set up. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to add IDLE's install directory to the PATH

Comment: Add IDLE path to your system's Environment Variables and give variable name as  "idle3"

Comment: I ticked the box "add Python 3.7 to PATH" when installing, if that is not what you are talking about can you explain what you mean please, thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: You have python in your PATH (you can write `python3` in your cmd), but not IDLE. IDLE is another program.

Comment: you may try to right click on item in start menu and maybe you will see context-menu with "Properties" . There can be full path to IDLE which you can use in command line. Later you can add folder in which is IDLE to variable PATH. This variable should be somewhere in system settings. There are many tutorials how to add fodler to PATH. I don't use Windows for longer time so it could changed.

Comment: I have added the folder "C:\Users\SSims\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7" to the Path enironment variable, which is where the IDLE properties page has as "location" but I am still receiving the same output from the cmd

Comment: Added the full answer below with all steps in detail, thank you all!

Comment: The school machine was likely something other than Windows.  'Using Python' in the doc set properly has separate chapters for *nix, Mac, and Windows.  In Windows, `py -m idlelib` should start IDLE.  I personally keep the IDLE icon pinned to my  taskbar.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy yep you're right, we were using fedora linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no step-by-step fixes that I have found online to answer this question, but many that answer specific portions of the question scattered around online.  Hopefully, this will help others with the same question in the future, as I know there are many who could benefit from this answer.

If you have selected "Add Python X.x to Path Variables" upon installation then you should be able to run "python" from the command line to start the python editor.  Similarly, this will allow you to do the same for IDLE.

First, hit your windows key and type "path" then enter to go to your system environment page in settings.

[image]

Next, click "Environment Variables then select "Path" under user variables
There should be a popup that contains a path that looks like this:

`C:\Users\SSims\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\`

Copy that address then click "new" 
Paste that address, then at the end of it type "Lib\idlelib" so that your new variable now looks like:

`C:\Users\SSims\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\idlelib`

This should be the path to the folder in which the idle executable file resides.

Note: You can check that path to ensure it is right by pasting it into the windows start menu and it should redirect you to the folder.  If it doesn't, you can paste the path to the python folder from earlier that was added automatically upon installation and search around in there until you find the idle executable, then add that folder to the Path variables to get it to work.

You should now be able to run the idle command from command prompt, hope this helps!!

Comment: Nowadays idlelib can be run as the main script, so you can run it via `py -m idlelib`, or for a specific version via `py -X[.Y[-32|-64]] -m idlelib`, or use `pyw` instead of `py` if you don't want a system console window. The py launcher, if installed, should always be available. If installed for all users, it's located in `"%SystemRoot%"`. If installed for the current user, it's located in `"%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\PyLauncher"`, which the installer adds to `PATH`.

Comment: Also, in Windows 10 we can get an `idle` command by switching to the app installation of Python 3 from the Microsoft Store. For 3.7, this installs an `idle` command as an app-exec link, as well as `idle3` and `idle3.7`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of IDLE use, **python -m idlelib** command

[check the IDLE official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html)